# Javascript based nested for loop along with Objects

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm new to javascript. when I was working with objects and nested loop. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EodiL1wo6xqNEPK4StcS?p=preview) is available

```
var a = [{b:[{c:null}]}]
for(var x= 0 ; x<10;x++){
  for(var y= 0 ; y<10;y++){
    console.log(a);
    a[x].b[y].c = y;
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

I was getting error like `TypeError: Cannot set property 'c' of undefined` can some one please explain why it is working like this. I was looking to have like this

```
a[0].b[0].c = 1;
a[0].b[1].c = 2;......
a[1].b[0].c = 1;....
a[9].b[9].c = 9;
```

Comment: What you wanted to do ? what is your expected output ?

Comment: `a[9].b[9].c = 9;` not work given that `var a = [{b:[{c:null}]}]`

Comment: how can i achieve like that if i required??

Comment: please some one help me how can I achieve like that type of output

Comment: atleast can anyone provide me blog or something so that i can understand

Comment: OP, you've shown that you understand how the loops will affect what's being assigned - but look at what you've wrote: `a[0].b[1].c = 2;` How can you try and assign to `c` of `b[1]` when `b[1]` doesn't exist? It doesn't have 2 elements, and since it's 0-based index, `1` is pointing to a second element. And it's not there. So it's like saying "give me 'c' of the second element". It can't do it, because the second element doesn't exist, let alone `c`.

Comment: but I'm trying to update the c of second element of b.right I think so...

Comment: @santhosh - yes, you are. But there is no second element. You can create a second element if you wish, but don't assume `c` is going to be there.

Comment: I understood thank you for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was getting error like TypeError: Cannot set property 'c' of
>   undefined can some one please explain why it is working like this

Because size of array `a` and `b` is 1 and moment your y becomes 1 which tries to access 2nd item in array b, it will return undefined (since that value doesn't exists).

so `b[1].c` -> `undefined.c` -> **error** (below)

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'c' of undefined

Comment: atleast can you provide me blog or something so that i can understand

Comment: @santhosh have a look at this document on looping and iteration https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration Can you specifically mention what exactly is confusing you?

Answer (score 2):

Because at the point it throws this error, `y` is greater than 0, but there is only 1 element in your `b` array.

I'm going to assume, in the console, you see:

`[object Object]`

`[object Object]`

`[object Object]`

And *then* the error. This would indicate the inner for loop is in its second iteration.

At the point your error occurs, you could interpret the code as:

```
a[0].b[1].c = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are iterating it 10 times, it should be iterated same times as the length of an array, so use `a.length` in first loop, and `a[x].b.length` in second loop.

```js
var a = [{b:[{c:null}]}]
for(var x= 0 ; x<a.length;x++){
  for(var y= 0 ; y<a[x].b.length;y++){
    console.log(a);
    a[x].b[y].c = y;
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

Combination of `Array.forEach` and `for..in`

```js
var a = [{b:[{c:"Test"}]}]

// a is Array. Use Array.forEach
a.forEach(function(item){
  
  // Check if current element is Object. If yes, use for..in
  if(typeof(item) === "object"){
    for(k in item){
      
      // Check if current item is Array and again loop over it
      if(Array.isArray(item[k])){
        item[k].forEach(function(o){
          
          // Print necessary value.
          console.log(o.c);
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please share what is missing in the answer. Thanks